# Cast object list to model

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to create a generic method to get a list of records from different tables. Based on my internet research I thought this would work but have been unable to make it work. A lot of code is omitted for clarity:

The method:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetEntityUpdates(string entity)
{
    string query = "select * from " + entity;
    IEnumerable<object> entityList;
    entityList = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>(query).ToList();
    return entityList;
}
```

This is then the calling code where I am attempting the cast which fails no matter how I spin it:

```
var theList = da.GetEntityUpdates("EntityName");
IEnumerable<EntityName> entityList = theList.Cast<EntityName>();
```

EntityName is a database model which corresponds to the select above.

InvalidCastException is then thrown.

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'EntityName'."

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unable to make it work? Are you getting an exception when you run the code? When you step through in debug mode, what is the value of `theList`?

Comment: Yes, InvalidCastException. Should have put that into the question.

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'EntityName'."

Comment: Why don't you try casting it as a List of type EntityName ( <List<EntityName>> instead of <EntityName>)... otherwise you might have to resort to Reflection. Also, if you're converting your collection to list inside the method, then why return it as an IEnumerable?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `GetEntityUpdates` to use generics. Entity Framework also has a `Set` method for DbContext that lets you access entities of a certain type. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEntityUpdates<T>() where T : class
{
    return db.Set<T>().ToList();
}
```

Then to call it you just pass in your entity class as a type parameter:

```
var foo = da.GetEntityUpdates<EntityName1>();
var bar = da.GetEntityUpdates<EntityName2>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you're using to extract information, `SqlQuery<object>`, relies on reflection in order to build your objects, not sure what framework is being used but would guess making your method generic would solve the problem

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEntityUpdates<T>(string entity)
{
    string query = "select * from " + entity;
    return db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Does the framework matter?